# PySpark - Resolving isnan errors with TimeStamp datatype

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, null, nan

I'm trying to create a function to check the quality of data (nans/nulls etc)
I have the following code running on a PySpark DataFrame

```
df.select([f.count(f.when((f.isnan(c) | f.col(c).isNull()), c)).alias(c) for c in cols_check]).show()
```

As long as the columns to check are strings/integers, I have no issue. However when I check columns with the datatype of `date` or `timestamp` I receive the following error:

> cannot resolve 'isnan(`Date_Time`)' due to data type mismatch:
> argument 1 requires (double or float) type, however, '`Date_Time`' is
> of timestamp type.;;\n'Aggregate...

There are clear null values in the column, how can I remedy this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `df.dtypes` to check the type of each column and be able to handle `timestamp` and `date` null count differently like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.select(*[
    (
        F.count(F.when((F.isnan(c) | F.col(c).isNull()), c)) if t not in ("timestamp", "date")
        else F.count(F.when(F.col(c).isNull(), c))
    ).alias(c)
    for c, t in df.dtypes if c in cols_check
]).show()
```

Comment: # List of Columns to Check
cols_check = ["VendorID","passenger_count"]